# Vacuum full faster?

Tags: postgresql

I notice that VACUUM FULL can take a very long time on Postgres.

Is there a way to speed up the process? e.g. by specifying that the DB is in maintenance mode and hence does not need to be available to any other request during the vacuuming?

Comment: Why do you need that at all? If you (have to) run that frequently, this typically indicates that auto-vacuum isn't configured correctly.

Comment: I don't have to run it frequently. I run it when I delete large swathes of data in the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [pg_prewarm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgprewarm.html) to load the table into RAM before you run `VACUUM (FULL)` on it.

Also, see that `maintenance_work_mem` is as big as possible; that will speed up the creation of indexes.

Both these things will help, but there is no magic to make it really fast.

Instead, you could try something like:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK oldtab IN SHARE MODE;  -- blocks modifications
CREATE TABLE newtab (LIKE oldtab INCLUDING ALL);
INSERT INTO newtab SELECT * FROM oldtab;
/* create indexes and constraints as appropriate */
DROP TABLE oldtab;
ALTER TABLE newtab RENAME TO oldtab;
COMMIT;
```

That will block `SELECT` statements only for a short while.

Comment: This is essentially what pg_repack does.

Comment: @mvd Not really. It does not lock the table while it is being rebuilt.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very general question, the answer will be the same:

Run `VACUUM FULL VERBOSE [table]` shows why slow

Most important parameter for vacuum is `maintenance_work_mem` try to increase it.

List of memory parameters: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-resource.html

Vacuum in depth:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-VACUUM-COST
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/routine-vacuuming.html

Also you can try https://reorg.github.io/pg_repack/ - vacuum without exclusively locks